# UIView Animation like Periscope app

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I want to re-create the animation that exists in the "Periscope" app.
In the app the user presses the screen and small hearts goes from the button right of the screen half way the the top and disappears from the screen.

I was wondering what would be the most efficient way of implementing this?
UIView animations / UIKit Dynamics / CABasicAnimation?

This is a screen shot from the app

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: I write a demo for the animation.
You can taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/31807301/4968501.

Answer (score 3):

You could create such an effect quite easily with particles in SpriteKit. It's exactly designed for creating such effects, especially in games, but it is also usable in normal apps. The interesting class is SKEmitterNode.

The official doc is here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEmitterNode_Ref/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Since UIKit Dynamics is a physics engine which is integrated to the UIkit it provides a option to create interface that feel real by adding behaviors such as gravity, attachments (springs) and forces. Also you can define the physical traits that you would like your interface elements to adopt.  Where as UIView has most powerful animatable property which takes a CGAFFineTransform. This is a matrix that expresses how each pixel of the UIView should be modified, applying some math formulas.

Pl. check the below links, which has very good examples of UIKit dynamics and Animation and what features can be acheived. I feel it might be good option to use UIKit dynamics because of the flexibility it provides.  http://www.sitepoint.com/using-uikit-dynamics-swift-animate-apps/

http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/uidynamics-in-swift/

http://mathewsanders.com/prototyping-iOS-iPhone-iPad-animations-in-swift/